# Symfony 1.4: About a new table / module

Tags: database, forms, module, symfony-1.4, backend

I am still not very familiar with Symfony 1.4 and a few things are still unclear to me.

**What I have done:**

1. I have recently added a new table to my Symfony 1.4 project's database (let's call it "A")
2. I have regenerated the **schema.yml** file using `$ php symfony doctrine:build-schema`.

**What I would like to do:**

When submitting the "add" form (in the `/new/` page) of another, different module, inserting a row in the "A" table.

-

In the future, I will need to fetch data from "A" and display them in the backend part of the website.

I don't have a backend module related to that new table. (Should I? How?)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do anything when you add a row to a table (let's call it `B` to distinguish from your `A`) you can use doctrine's lifecycle hooks, the `pre`s and `post`s. In your case it could be a `postInsert`. (you can also use `Save`, `Update`, `Delete`, each with `pre` or `post`).

Each of this functions is executed in a given moment (before or after an event) of a given event. The `Save` hook is executed after any inserts or updates so you don't have to copy functionality to two functions.

You should implement the method in your `B` class and add a row to `A`.

To answer your other question - it's best if you use the Symfony's admin generator and create a module for `A`. You will have a list of all the rows, possibility to filter the list and to modify the rows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is my understanding that the `postInsert` function should be in the `/lib/model/doctrine/"B".class.php`. But I am not sure about the rest. How can I create a module for "A" and a model in `/lib/model/doctrine/` ?

Comment: You can create the model classes automatically running `./symfony doctrine:build --all-classes` from the console. As for generating a module in the backend have a look here: http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/12?orm=Doctrine